# What's the difference between curly braces and normal brackets in RxJava with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I don't understand the real difference between the curly braces and and the normal brackets in Kotlin when using RxJava. For example, I have the following code which works as expected:

```
someMethodThatReturnsCompletable()
    .andThen(anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable())
    .subscribe(...)
```

But the following does NOT work:

```
someMethodThatReturnsCompletable()
    .andThen { anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable() }
    .subscribe(...)
```

Note the difference in the `andThen()` part of the chain with the curly braces. I can't understand what the difference between the two is. I've had a look at some articles but unfortunately I am still having difficulty in understanding this subtle difference.

Comment: My question is not about behaviour - but the difference between the two braces - how/why are they different in this instance?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first code segment executes `anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable()` and passes the return value to `andThen()`, where a `Completable` is accepted as parameter.

In the second code segment, you are writing a function literal as a [lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions-and-lambdas). It passes a function of type `() -> Unit` to `andThen()`, which it also a valid statement, but the code inside the lambda may not be called.

> In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter to a function is a function, and you're passing a lambda expression as the corresponding argument, you can specify it outside of parentheses:
>
> ```
> lock (lock) {
>     sharedResource.operation()
> }
> ```

Since Kotlin support [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions),

> This means that Kotlin function literals can be automatically converted into implementations of Java interfaces with a single non-default method, as long as the parameter types of the interface method match the parameter types of the Kotlin function.

Looking back to `Completable`, there are several overloaded `andThen()` functions:

```
andThen(CompletableSource next)
andThen(MaybeSource<T> next)
andThen(ObservableSource<T> next)
andThen(org.reactivestreams.Publisher<T> next)
andThen(SingleSource<T> next)
```

Here you can specify the SAM Type by calling:

```
andThen( CompletableSource {
    //implementations
})
```

Answer (score 8):

As you probably know that in Java `()` brackets are used for passing parameters and `{}` braces are used for method body and also represents the body of lambda expression.

So lets compare:

1. `.andThen(anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable())` :
   here andThen() method accepts `Completable` so andThen will save reference to the completable returned by `anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable()` method to subscribe later.
2. `.andThen { anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable() }` : This passes lambda expression to andThen method. Here `anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable()` is not invoked at the time of passing the lambda. `anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable()` will be called when lambda function is invoked in andThen method.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

`()` -> You are passing something inside them i.e. function arguments

`{}` -> You are executing something inside them. i.e. expression

Answer (score 1):

`.andThen(anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable())` means that the result of `anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable()` will be passed to `andThen()`

`.andThen { anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable() }` means that the lambda, that executes `anotherMethodThatReturnsACompletable()` will be passed to `andThen()`