# confusion with onExceptionResumeNext passing a observable as a lambda expression

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

```
io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.13
kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
```

I have the following Observable and I am trying to throw an exception to test the capture of the exception in OnError. However, when I pass in the following to the `onExceptionResumeNext(Observable.just(10))` I get the following output:

```
1
2
10
onComplete

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6)
            .doOnNext {
                if (it == 0) {
                    throw RuntimeException("Exception on 0")
                }
            }
            .onExceptionResumeNext(Observable.just(10))
            .subscribe(
                    {
                        println(it)
                    },
                    {
                        println("onError ${it.message}")
                    },
                    {
                        println("onComplete")
                    } )
}
```

However, If I pass a lambda expression to that method I get the following output:

```
1
2

 Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6)
            .doOnNext {
                if (it == 0) {
                    throw RuntimeException("Exception on 0")
                }
            }
            .onExceptionResumeNext { Observable.just(10) }
            .subscribe(
                    {
                        println(it)
                    },
                    {
                        println("onError ${it.message}")
                    },
                    {
                        println("onComplete")
                    } )
}
```

Just wondering what is the difference between doing this `onExceptionResumeNext(Observable.just(10))` and doing this `onExceptionResumeNext { Observable.just(10) }`

Many thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731647/whats-the-difference-between-curly-braces-and-normal-brackets-in-rxjava-with-ko

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in the first case you passing observable to `onExceptionResumeNext`

in case of error in original observable, you'll be resubscribed to observable that is passed to `onExceptionResumeNext`

that's why you're getting "1" and "2" from original source and then "10" and "onComplete" from `Observable.just(10)`

in second case, you're using lambda syntax, so you're effectively doing this:

```
.onExceptionResumeNext(object : ObservableSource {
    void subscribe(@NonNull Observer<? super T> observer) {
        Observable.just(10)
    }
})
```

as you can see, `observer` that is passed to you is not getting subscribed. Thus, nothing is emmited after "1" and "2" from initial source

what you should be doing is

```
.onExceptionResumeNext { observer ->
    Observable.just(10).subscribe(observer)
}
```